# How to find folders over 1GB and execute another command in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, console

I want to find the folders which sizes are over 1GB and then if they are over then I want to erase them.

I found some commands like

```
find /some/path -type d -size +1G -exec ls {} \;
```

or

```
du -h /some/path | grep ^[0-9.]*G
```

or
(over 600M)

```
du -h /some/path/ | grep ^[6-9][0-9][0-9][0-9.]*M | sort
```

But these two commands are not really helping to me because the find command is not finding any folders although there are folders over 1GB but the linux thinks they are some small KB. Is there any command to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common problem when dealing with file/directory names is when they contain whitespace. *nix filepaths can even contain `\n` newlines.  To get around all whitespace issues, you need to work with a **null** delimiter `\x00`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Parameter 1 ("$1"):  Remove sub-directories from this directory
# Parameter 2 ("$2"):  Remove sub-directories larger than this many bytes 
#
# Example, To remove sub-directories bigger than 1 GB from your HOME directory
#   
#    script "$HOME"  $((2**30))     
#        
dir="$1"; shopt -s extglob; dir="${dir%%+(/)}"  # remove trailing / from directory path
[[ -d "$dir" ]] || { echo "\$1: directory NOT found: $1"; exit 1; }

size=$2  # size in bytes
[[ -z $2 || -n ${2//[0-9]} ]] && { echo "\$2: size-threshold must be numeric: $2"; exit 2; }

du -0b "$dir" |                        # output with \x00 as end-of-path
 sort -zrn  |                          # sort dirs,largest first
  awk -vRS="\x00" -vORS="\x00" -v"size=$size" -v"dir=$dir" -v"prev=\x00" '{
     if( $1<=size ) next               # filter by size; skip small dirs
     match( $0, "\x09" )               # find du TAB-delimiter           
     path = substr( $0, RSTART+1 )     # get directory path 
     if( path ~ "^"dir"/*$" ) next     # filter base dir; do not kill it! 
     match( path, "^" prev ".+" )      # print (ie. process) parent dirs only
     if( RSTART == 0 ) { print path }
     prev = path }' |
   xargs -0 -I{} echo rm -vr {}        # remove the `echo` to run live!!!!
```

Comment: where should i write the path in this script?

Comment: If you save the script as `rm-dirs-gt`, the you can just call it from the command-line as: `rm-dirs-gt "$HOME"`  (or whatever path you choose) ...  The size threshold , which must be specified in  ***bytes***, is currently hard-coded as `$((2**30))`, which   is 1GB ... It would be quite simple to have it as a second parameter ... I'll add the size-threshold parameter to my answer.

Comment: i got `du illegal option -- 0` and `awk: invalid -v option` error from this script

Comment: Which version of `du` and `awk` are you using? Mine is `du (GNU coreutils) 7.4`, and `GNU Awk 3.1.6`.. With `awk` the variables can also be passed as args, but the `-v` method it the preferred way.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, the code works! can you exclude the main folder from removing?

Comment: It should already be excluded... and that's why the `echo` before the rm is very important, while testing... Are you actually seeing the main directory being shown as a command for removal? .. This is the line which should take car of that `if( path ~ "^"dir"/*$" ) next     # filter base dir; do not kill it!` ... it and the initial stripping of `/` from the directory parameter `$1`

Comment: ohh the old script was ok! now with this new script where should i write the directory path?

Comment: you are right i dont see the main directory.. the old script works great thanks!

Comment: The active part of the script is the same; only the manner of passing the second parameter `$2` has changed; plus there is some basic parameter validation.  Just run `scrpt-name "$HOME" $((2..30))` at the command-line... or whatever *directory-path* and *size-threshold* you choose (size is in ***bytes***)

Comment: i changes this `script "/some/path/"  $((2**30))` and i got this: 
`/some/path/: Is a directory
Terminated`

Comment: `script` is just an generic indicator for whatever name you choose to save the script as:  Just use the name you save it as (instead of *"script"*)  ... Note that you must make scripts executable by running the command `chmod +x my-script` ...(where *my-script* is whatever name you decide to save it as)...  A good generally used directory to put your scripts in is a subdirectory called `bin` in you home directory ...  Also you can add that `bin` directory to you `$PATH`, so you can run it via its name only, otherwise you need to specify its path.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is a terrible idea.  This is mostly because of how what you asked for works: If a folder `foo` contains more than 1GB, every parent folder of `foo` also contains more than that (because it contains the folder `foo`).

Thus, if you scan `/home/myuser/myfolder/` for things larger, and `/home/myuser/myfolder/bar/quz/baz/foo` is, `/home/myuser/myfolder/bar/quz/baz`, `/home/myuser/myfolder/bar/quz/` `/home/myuser/myfolder/bar/`, and `/home/myuser/myfolder/` will all be marked for deletion.

You can get around this with the -S option to du.

This gives a result (THAT I DO NOT RECOMMEND RUNNING)

```
du -Sb $DIR | grep '^[0-9]\{10\}' | cut -f 2- | xargs -d "\n" rm -rf
```

This will fail on directories whose names contain newline characters.  Fixing it to not have that flaw is left as an exercise to the reader.

If you want another size make up a regex to match it. `du -b` returns sizes in bytes, so work from there.  HINT: 365MB or more would be `'^\([0-9]\{10\}\|[4-9][0-9]\{8\}\|3[7-9][0-9]\{7\}\|36[6-9][0-9]\{6\}\)'`.

Comment: yes i know i want to delete all the folders because if they are over 1GB i dont need them any more..

Comment: do u know how can i exlude the main folder from remove?

Comment: i think i found out, but the problem is the /path/ is getting removed also
`du -h /some/path/ | grep ^[0-9.]*G | cut -f 2- | xargs echo rm -rf`

Comment: is there any way remove the main folder from selection? for example `/home/myuser/myfolder/` will be not removed with that command

Comment: "You can get around this with the -S option to du."-- though that will still get flagged if that directory itself has too many large files.  Solution I guess would be `du -Sb $DIR/*`, so you're not ever running it on the `$DIR` in question.

Answer (score 1):

To find folders larger than 10G:
`du -h /mnt/backup/ |awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]*G/ {print}' |sort -nr|sed 's/G//g' |awk '{ if ( $1 > 10.0 ) print }'`

You can change the 10.0 to any number and /mnt/backup to any path, it will print out folders that match with their size in GBs.

Answer (score 1):

**Caution** deletes all the Files & Directories above 1GB in the given path

du -sh -t1000000000 /some/path/* | awk -F" " '{print $2}' | xargs rm -rf

Answer (score 0):

use `du -h` to get a list of the files and directories with their sizes. Then you can use `sed` to extract the folder names you want to erase and pass them to `rm`. This can be implemented as a bash script or a command on any shell you like. 
If you need more help in writing the command, let me know. Though reading the man pages of the above commands should help you accomplish your task.

Comment: can u give me an example script for this situation? thanks

Comment: See if someone can help you with the sed script. I have just started learning sed. Will try and cook up a script if I can.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the folders using `du -sm * | awk '$1 > 1000'`

Comment: This appears to be very similar to other answers. Can you go into a little more detail on what is different with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This command finds all folders bigger than 1GB:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 |grep G |sed s/G//g |awk '$1>1'
```

Since we work actually in TB: The following command finds all folders bigger than 150 GB:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 |grep G |sed s/G//g |awk '$1>150' && du -h --max-depth=1 |grep T |sed s/T//g |awk '$1>1'| grep -v "."
```